# Null parameter check C++

Tags: c++, parameters, null, nullptr, kinematics

I have a function that solves one of 4 kinematic equations. The parameters are floats, and Is there a way to distinguish between a NULL parameter and a parameter with a value of 0. I've read up on the subject and it seems that NULL and 0 are the same. The reason I want to distinguish a 0 from a form of "nothingness" is because a 0 value assigns a value and "nothingness" shows that we don't know what that value is.

```
float doSomething(float& foo, float& bar, float& goo, float& baz){
    if(foo == (insert_null_value_here)){
        return (foo_after_we_did_some_equation);
    }
}
```

The "null" value can't be NULL or 0 as I already discussed. If the parameters were all pointers to floats, would this work if I checked for "nullptrs"?(Not my main question) Even if the former question is yes, what value can I use for non-pointer/reference types?(Re-statement of main question)

Comment: Feel free to question for further clarification.

Comment: You cannot check references against `NULL`, what you can try is `if(&foo == NULL)`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why would that be reasonable here?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Probably not, just mentioned it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Please don't "just mention" UB things.

Comment: @anoyd_bi_me_grammers: How do you "check for dangling pointers"?

Comment: I was thinking that instead of having references as parameters, the were pointers to floats, and I would check if the pointers were nullptr(s). When I called the function I'd pass nullptr as parameters. (thanks to Swtsvn for seeing through that)

Comment: @anoyd_bi_me_grammers: Okay so you can do that then. Note though that this has nothing to do with "dangling pointers", which are undetectable.

Comment: I will edit to rectify.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ a valid reference is never allowed to reference a null location. An optimizing compiler can use that to infer that the `if` statement can't be taken, and remove it entirely.

Comment: When you declare a parameter as a reference, there must always be a real object behind it. Declaring the parameters to be a reference to a non-const object implies you intend to alter the value of the object that was passed in. Is that truly your intention, given you want to test for the case of "nothing was passed in"?

Comment: Yes, that is my case, because I am altering every other value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding my 2 cents here.

You could also use pointers directly, and send nullptr for parameters that you do not want to send values for. This is, in case you do not want to include Boost for a minor feature.

Also you cannot check references for nullptr. They are supposed to have a proper address by default.

Comment: References do not have addresses.

Comment: I'd have to say that Boost is very useful, but not for such a minor feature, and I want the ability to change the float values with simplicity.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the address-of operator `&` works on them just the same.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No, the address-of operator is applied to the referent. `[C++11: 8.3.2/5]` states: _"**There shall be** no references to references, no arrays of references, and **no pointers to references**._" You cannot take the address of a reference. It is simply impossible. A notion for which the language does not provide. References, as distinct from pointers, are aliases rather than "objects" in their own right (though this abstraction does sadly yet unavoidably leak in a couple of places, such as storing references as data members).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit indeed it is, which is why one might be tempted to use it to see if the referent is a dereferenced null pointer. Except of course that dereferencing a null pointer leads to undefined behavior, see my comment on the question for an example.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Right - as I said in my answer 45 minutes ago, references cannot compliantly "be null". You've invoked UB and it's too late. I don't really follow what you're trying to say at this point!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it seemed that you were arguing the final point in this answer, not just mentioning a technicality. I commented not necessarily for your benefit but to clarify the issue for other readers.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as "a null parameter". Those references cannot compliantly "be null".

(It's important not to conflate this with the idea of a null pointer, which used to have value *zero* for legacy reasons — with a macro `NULL` defined to be *zero* for "convenience" — but nowadays is `nullptr`.)

If you want to make those values optional, use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), which forms a wrapper around a data member and a boolean indicating whether the member is populated:

```
float doSomething(boost::optional<float>& foo)
{
   if (foo) {
      return someEquation(foo.get());
   }

   return somethingElse();
}
```

Now, valid values are:

- `3.5f`
- `42`
- `0`
- `-5`

And to pass no value at all:

- `boost::none`

If you want to keep the ref-to-non-`const`, you'd do something like:

```
boost::optional<float> myValue = 3;  // or 42, or 5.1, or boost::none
doSomething(myValue);
```

---

<sub>[`boost::optional` was nearly `std::optional` as of C++14, but is now part of the Library Fundamentals TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) that [we hope will make it, in entirety, into C++17](https://isocpp.org/std/status).</sub>

Comment: *"boost::optional was nearly std::optional"*... this seems to be the case very often, look at `<thread>`. `boost` seems to be the `C++` beta playground. (Note this comment has nothing to do with your post, it just got me on a side rant)

Comment: @Cyber: Boost is absolutely the C++ standard library playground. :)

Comment: And if foo = 0, it wont be considered false? Only if boost::none is the actual parameter?

Comment: @anoyd_bi_me_grammers: Correct.

Comment: Hmm, I was expecting if(0){} to not work since 0 is false when converted.

Comment: @anoyd_bi_me_grammers `if (foo)` where `foo` is a `boost::optional` object only checks to see if the optional object *has a value*. It doesn't actually *look at the value itself*.

Comment: Maybe just make `doSomething` take an `optional` by-value? Answer reads a little confusingly otherwise, even with your caveat at the end.

Comment: @anoyd_bi_me_grammers: But the code does not do that. Foo is in fact never `= 0` ... it is an object that potentially wraps the value `0`. It has its own conversions that are designed to run this test properly for you. That's the entire point! Notice how I had to write `foo.get()` to actually get the underlying `float` value.

Comment: @Barry: The OP's code takes a `float` by reference and I assume there's actually a reason for that.